# Java: Populate ArrayList from CSV file and remove duplicates-- common methods not working

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, file-io

I want to take the contents of a CSV file and remove the duplicates in it. This is a topic that's gotten a lot of coverage here and elsewhere, but none of the suggested methods work for me: the final result still contains the duplicate values.

These are the steps I'm taking to get the text from the CSV file:

```
String holder = "";

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:"+File.separator+"followers.csv")).useDelimiter(",");


List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

while (input.hasNext())
{

    holder = input.next();
    temp.add(holder);

}

input.close();
```

So far, so good.

After trying to turn the ArrayList into a LinkedHashSet and a whole lot else, to no avail, this is what I'm on currently:

```
List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String s : temp) 
        {
            if (!finalList.contains(s))
            {
                finalList.add(s);
            }
        }

        finalList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

But finalList still contains the duplicate values.

I'm assuming the problem lies with how I'm getting the CSV values into the ArrayList in the first place, but I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that there are duplicates? A set will not store duplicates and the above loop will not add duplicates either. Either there's something going on not in the code you posting, or there may be an encoding issue where the characters look the same but are in fact different.

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I'm using a test CSV file that just has the words "one", "two", "two" and "three". Obviously I'm expecting the redundant "two" to be omitted.

Comment: There's some critical information missing. Make sure you include all of your code, including the CSV file. Also, include what gets logged in your `forEach`. If you log the values in `temp`, is it what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution to remove duplicates (without keeping the order) is

```
    Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();

    //assume the ArrayList temp contains your data with duplicates
    hs.addAll(temp);
    temp.clear();
    temp.addAll(hs);
```

temp then contains your data without duplicates.

Comment: A `HashSet` will not preserve the order of the data, which is presumably why the OP had tried to use a `LinkedHashSet`. This is just another way of solving the same problem and doesn't explain why their solution doesn't work.

Comment: Tried this, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting whitespaces and new lines mixed with your values, hence the duplicates. Try parsing with [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) `CsvParser` as it eliminates these for you, works faster, and gives you much better support for handling the CSV format in general.

Try this to eliminate your dupes:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");

// creates a CSV parser
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

// parses all rows in one go.
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new File("C:"+File.separator+"followers.csv")));

Set<String> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(String[] row : allRows){
    for(String element : row){
        if(element != null){
            //assuming the case of these these elements don't matter
            //remove the ".toLowerCase()" part if it does.
            result.add(element.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(result); //here's your deduplicated data.
```

Hope it helps.

Disclosure: I'm the author of this libary, it's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 License)